# How can I project mouse coordinates to the world with a rotated camera?

Tags: godot

The [project_position](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera.html#class-camera-method-project-position) method in Camera works perfectly if the camera is pointed directly downwards (-90 degrees), but there is significant error in aim point vs mouse position if the camera is rotated to not be directly downwards. See images below for visual examples.

One pattern I noticed is the aim is behind the mouse in quadrants 1 and 3, but in front of the mouse in quadrants 2 and 4. For use cases where mouse x = 0 or z = 0, the aim vs mouse accuracy is perfect.

The way godot RayCast works, it requires a cast_to point. So it feels like this makes it difficult to use this to implement my own mouse to world coords.

-90 degrees camera rotation
[image: -90 degrees rotation]

-60 degrees camera rotation
[image: -60 degrees rotation]

With mouse over top right box, projected 3d world point should be near 10, y = 2, -10, but we can see in the output the world point the camera projected to and what the character is rotated to
[image: mouse should be near 10, y = 2, -10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Godot 3.5.1. The solution lies in [godot docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/ray-casting.html) describing raycasting. Here's what I collected from a few doc pages.

```
func handle_mouse_aim():
    var mouse_coords = camera.get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    
    var from = camera.project_ray_origin(mouse_coords)
    var to = from + camera.project_ray_normal(mouse_coords) * 1_000
    var space = get_world().direct_space_state
    
    # ( Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Array exclude=[ ], int collision_mask=2147483647, bool collide_with_bodies=true, bool collide_with_areas=false )
    # the only thing in this layer should be our world area adjusted at character eye level
    var intersection = space.intersect_ray(from, to, [], 32768, false, true)
    if intersection:
        look_at(intersection["position"], Vector3.UP)
```

I call this method in my `_physics_process` in my character.gd script that `extends KinematicBody`

Extra: `1_000` is the length of the vector of the raycast. `32768` is the value of the layer (I use layer 16 only in my collision_layer for my MouseAimLayer area). These are magic numbers and could be defined or accessed from elsewhere.
[image: solution showing my scene in godot]